# wordpress wp_insert_user function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am in the process of creating a custom registration form for WordPress. 
My problem is adding custom user meta. I believe the function `wp_insert_user` will only allow you to add the default fields within the WordPress user table.

Here is my current test code:

```
$username = '12344';
$password = '1111';
$user_data = array(
'ID' => '',
'user_pass' => $password,
'user_login' => $username,
'display_name' => $loginName,
'first_name' => $firstName,
'last_name' => $lastName,
'role' => get_option('default_role') ,
'user_secondry_email' => 'test@tst.com'// Use default role or another role, e.g. 'editor'
);
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
wp_hash_password( $password );
```

I have found the `add_user_meta` function, but this requires an ID to add the metadata. Obviously the user hasn't been created yet so they won't have an ID. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For what I understand from the [Wordpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user), the `ID` field is optional.

If it is present, the user is updated, if not, it is created and the `ID` of the new user is returned by the function.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your problem correctly  you want to add new user_meta to the current registered user.

Here's how I did it.

```
// this code insert the user, same on your code above just remove the ID field :)
$new_userid = wp_insert_user( $user_data );

$is_success = add_user_meta( $new_userid, 'position', 'programmer', true );
if( $is_success  ) {
   echo 'Successfully added';
} else {
   echo 'Error on user creation';
}

**NOTE:**
$new_userid = Is the return value from adding our new user and use that ID in adding new user meta
```

Hope this help and other user looking for same solution.

Answer (score 2):

After digging deeper, and checking on my end, I found this script will work just fine. Remove that get_option function and this

```php
$user_data = array(
    'user_login' => $username,
    'user_email' => $email,
    'first_name' => $firstname,
    'last_name' => $lastname,
    'display_name' => $firstname.' '.$lastname,
    'user_pass' => $u_password,
    'role' => 'administrator'
);
$result = wp_insert_user($user_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ID value from the array completely and it should work.  (e.g. remove 'ID' => '')

Also, I don't think "user_secondary_email" is an allowed field for the new user array.  The field list is here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user

(In your example, the "user_secondry_email" is missing an 'a')

Good luck!